# How to combine embedded columns with other input data in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, embedding

I have one column with categorical data with 1003 different categories, and I have a lot of columns with regular integer data. I want to embed the column with categorical data and have the embedded output together with all the other columns as input to my model. I am unsure of how to do this but have tried in the following code using merge. Unfortunately, this gives a **Value error: '"concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output shapes except for the concat axis. Layer shapes: [(None, 1, 11), (None, 53)]'**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    hidden_layers  = [1000,500,500]


    embedding = Sequential()
    embedding.add(1003, 11, input_length = 1))

    model1 = Sequential()
    model1.add(Dense(53, input_dim=53, activation='relu'))

    model = Sequential()
    model = model.add(Merge([embedding, model1], mode = 'concat'))

    for i, layer_size in enumerate(hidden_layers):
        model.add(Dense(layer_size, activation='relu'))

    model.add(Dense(self.output_layers, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Embedding](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) layer produces a 3D tensor as you see in the error message (None, 1, 11) where 1 is the *sequence length* you are embedding. In order to merge with a 2D tensor you would have to Flatten it:

```
embedding = Sequential()
embedding.add(Embedding(1003, 11, input_length = 1))
embedding.add(Flatten())
```

which will give (None, 11) and can be merged with (None, 53).

Comment: It works! But no I get a new issue where it says that says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'"  on this line in the for-loop: "model.add(Dense(layer_size, activation='relu'))"

Comment: You overwrite model with return value of `model.add` which is None right before the for loop.

Comment: Because it returns None, model.add adds the layer and doesn't return anything. You might be confusing with the functional API.

Comment: so how should I do it when I want to use Embedding on some input-columns but not all?

Comment: You should switch to [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) two have multi-input models.